# Android - open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) in /mnt

Tags: java, android, genymotion

I am trying to create a file in a shared folder (between the [emulator running Android](https://www.genymotion.com/) and the host system running Ubunut) in: /mnt/shared/androidShared

I added the necessary lines to my manifest file to not have permission issues:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yalishanda.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Yet when trying to create the file I get this erros:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/shared/androidShared/test.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

The corresponding code:

```
   public void onButtonTap(View v){

        String filepath ="/mnt/shared/androidShared/test.txt";
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream (new File("/mnt/shared/androidShared/test.txt"));
            byte[] buffer = "This will be writtent in test.txt".getBytes();
            fos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I also tried to escape the backslashes as follows:

```
//mnt//shared//androidShared//test.txt"
```

But the error is still the same.

Why can't I create the file? Even when I create the file in advance and just try to write to it I get the same error.

The exception is being thrown when this line is executed:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream (new File("/mnt/shared/androidShared/test.txt"));
```

I tried those approaches as well, without any success: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25364833/

How can I create a file in this folder?

Thanks!

Comment: "I am trying to create a file in a shared folder (between the emulator running Android and the host system running Ubunut) in: /mnt/shared/androidShared" -- how are you attempting to create the shared folder? I am not aware that this is an available option.

Comment: @CommonsWare I meant shared file not folder.

Comment: OK, how are you attempting to create the shared file? I am not aware that this is an available option.

Comment: @CommonsWare well, the emulator allows to use a shared folder, ie a folder accessible to both parties inside /mnt. How do I create a file? See main post...

Comment: Your question appears to be specific to Genymotion, which I don't use. The Android SDK emulator does not have this feature. I edited your question to be clearer about that point.

Comment: @CommonsWare i recently read the https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Files/FilesEditor sample of your. And it mention of using getFilesDir,
getExternalFilesDir or
getExternalStoragePublicDirectory as advisable to access via this. But we cannot access the /mnt directory as it throw SecurityException. It will be helpful if you give an answer. Thanks in advance to his question.

Comment: @CommonsWare the /mnt directory exists no matter whether you use Genymotion or not. Now I don't see why it would be impossible to create a file in a directory on a system running Android, regardless of Genymotion.

Comment: @Killer: "But we cannot access the /mnt directory as it throw SecurityException" -- correct. "It will be helpful if you give an answer" -- do not try accessing the `/mnt` directory on production hardware.

Comment: "the /mnt directory exists no matter whether you use Genymotion or not" -- correct. "Now I don't see why it would be impossible to create a file in a directory on a system running Android" -- well, first, that is not exactly what you are trying to do. You are "trying to create a file in a shared file (between Genymotion running Android and the host system running Ubunut)", according to your question. Second, on production devices, ordinary apps do not have read/write access to arbitrary filesystem locations. You're welcome to pursue root options for that, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have no other easy choice in my case but access this folder. I need to activate some scripts on the host system whenever the VM needs to. AFAIK I can either use TCP/IP either try to access the host straight. For the latter only one solution: use the shared folder.

Comment: "I have no other easy choice in my case but access this folder" -- then choose a non-easy choice, or see if Genymotion has some specific capabilities related to this. The Android SDK emulator does not, and production hardware does not.

Comment: @CommonsWare what other easier options are there? I m really pissed off, I am so close. All I need to do to finish this part is to be able to create at that specific location.

Comment: "what other easier options are there?" -- use TCP/IP, as you mentioned. For example, have a tiny Web service on the host that your code on the emulator can connect to. This also offers better possibilities for security, which may be important depending on what you will have running on this emulator.

Comment: @CommonsWare How can using a TCP/IP connection be more secure? in my case it will have no other choice than use a sim card or smth to obtain an ip address via DHCP in order to be able to send tcp packets to the host . No TCP/IP = no hack (unless physical access). Feel free to correct me.

Comment: "in my case it will have no other choice than use a sim card" -- well, no, because you are using an emulator. Your "shared file" approach, at best, could only work with an emulator, and your documentation that you pointed to is for the Genymotion emulator. And it is generally more risky to have direct filesystem access than access mediated by some sort of server.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am running all of this on a portable embedded device (the VM is being ran on the embedded device as well). how am I supposed to obtain an ip address except by using a sim card?  I can t carry a router in my pocket all day long to do DHCP to provide 2 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

> I am running all of this on a portable embedded device

What you want is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices or with custom firmware. Android does not directly support SFTP, SMB/CIFS, or any other filesystem-level shared file solution.

Even if you do modify your device to support this, your device will need access to the SFTP, SMB/CIFS, or other file server.

Note that your question links to documentation from Genymotion, which is an emulator, not a device.

An alternative would be to run some sort of app server (e.g., a Web service) instead of a file server, and access that from your app code on the device. This would not require rooting or alterations to the device firmware.

Comment: very strange, it is possible for me to add ifles to /mnt/shared/androidShared from my host at runtime and access them from inside my VM but not the other way around. I can read the files So it looks to me like this should work. It is purely creating a file in a folder I don't think there is any "complex" protocol like SFTP or so going on there.

Comment: @LandonZeKepitelOfGreytBritn: Just because Genymotion offers some feature for an emulator directly running on Ubuntu does not mean that the same feature is somehow available for arbitrary Android hardware and by some means that does not involve a network.

Comment: Don't get me wrong I am not rejecting your explanation or whatsoever. I am explaining what I see and what I infer from it. I am open for you to correct me and prove me wrong. It sucks to be stuck at a technical issue. If TCP/IP is the only easy way to go, well then I guess I ll look into it.

Comment: yes, I am able to create a file in this directory if I am root. Not sure how legal it is to root my VM...